# Marketing API - System user permissions missing, using dev tier

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-permissions

We implemented the Marketing API into our company's order management system to automate the creation of ad campaigns. A system user was created with the proper permissions, and the integration has been working. We're only using the API for our own ad account and pages, which we of course own. The "Facebook App" is set to live mode and has been for a couple weeks now.

But starting sometime today, we have been getting errors saying that the `ads_read` and `ads_management` permissions are required. And sure enough, they are indeed missing from the access token for the system user when I use the access token debugger.

What would have caused the system user to be missing these permissions all of a sudden? We are still on the dev tier and have only recently reached the 1,500 calls required to request standard access. That's the only thing I can think of so far, but is that the reason we suddenly don't have the proper permissions, or could it be something else? I haven't read anywhere in the documentation that we would lose these permissions upon reaching 1,500 calls, and I was planning on requesting the standard access next.

Also, I have read in various spots: "You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people." That is actually our case, as we are only using a system user for the API calls, and there are only a few users tied to the Facebook ad account. So, do we need to submit our app for review?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Our app was created a month ago and the APIs were working fine in the DEV tier. From Monday the APIs are erring out saying "Requires ads_management permission to manage the object". Im assuming Facebook must have changed some policies from their side and without upgrading to standard access the APIs will fail. Im searching for some docs to validate this but not finding anything. Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: Also facing the same issue. Unable to use anything in sandbox that requires the use of the ads_management permissions. Has either of you already raised a bug on this issue? If so, can you link the bug below so i can further add to the issue.

Comment: I would submit for review asking for required permissions. Seems fastest way with a changing API.